# Make python talk to local Flask app via browser

Tags: javascript, python, flask, local

This might be a simple architecture question but I can't figure it out.

### What I have:

Basically I have two apps running locally on my Raspberry pi:

- One C++ app ([Voicecommand](https://github.com/StevenHickson/PiAUISuite)) that allows me to execute commands from my microphone and run various python scripts. On certain keywords, I can run a python script to open the browser or do anything.
- One simple Flask app, with a couple of basic views

### What I want:

When I say a keyword (e.g. weather), I want my local Flask app to return the weather (already have the function and view for this), ideally in small frame without reloading the whole page.

### What I thought about:

I thought about having my local app making JS calls within the browser but couldn't really figure out how. Best thing I could think of was an equivalent of Applescript to inject the JS call in the browser... From then, I could easily make an ajax call to my weather view and return the result without refreshing the page.
I also thought about using something like React or Angular, or connecting the two apps but I'm not 100% sure on how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat tricky because you want to update a client based on some event on the server, where normally the interaction is all one way (i.e. client makes a request, server responds, that's it).

What I would do is set up some sort of two way protocol, such as WebSockets. One decent library for Flask is [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). You can then have your Python scripts from the C++ app hit an endpoint in your Flask app, and that endpoint can `emit()` a message to the client. On the [client side](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-client), you can receive these events and update your views accordingly.